# How do I refer to the value of an external concept from within a result-view?

Tags: bixby

How do I bring the value of an external concept into a result view? What I have is:

```
 result-view {
 match: AltBrainsData (this) 

      message {
        if (size(this) > 1) {
        template ("Here are some AltBrains I found on search term")
        }
        else-if (size(this) == 0 )
     {template ("I couldn't find any AltBrains matching that search term")}  }
```

What I want is to say "on search term #{value(searchterm)}" which is an optional parameter in the initial search function. but the result view doesn't seem to know about the concept.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
result-view {
 match: AltBrainsData (this)
 from-output: <NameOfAction> (action)

      message {
        if (size(this) > 1) {
        template ("Here are some AltBrains I found on #{value(action.searchTerm)}")
        }
        else-if (size(this) == 0 )
     {template ("I couldn't find any AltBrains matching that #{value(action.searchTerm)}")}  }
```

Here is another example from the documentationat https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/customizing-plan.match-patterns

```
dialog (Result) {
  match: PercentDailyCholesterol (this) {
    min (Required) max (One)
    from-property: NutritionInformation (source)
  }
  template ("One portion of #{value(source.food)} will meet #{percent(this)} of your daily needs for cholesterol.")
}
```

Comment: Looks like from-output needs to be enclosed in { }

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code, one additional thought, instead of `(size(this) == 0 )` you could also use `NoResult` e.g.

```
dialog (NoResult)
```

There are more complex options available as well. In an action, you can specify what happens if there is empty output e.g.

```
 output (Result) {
    on-empty {
       . . . [On empty markup]
    }
 }
```

This allows you to do change the input and re-execute - there are several options see https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/customizing-plan.effects#handling-empty-output